# Call Function to another class

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I have problems to pass the variables to another file, I already realize the code and I do not find the solution, it sends me error in the function

> onclick="limit();javascript:AyudaTipos(2)"/>

function

```
function limit (){


 $.ajax({
            url: 'Tipos.php',
            type: 'POST', // GET or POST
             data: {"acreedor":$("#acreedor").val(),"importe2":$("#importe2").val(),
            success: function(data) { // data is the response from your php script
                // This function is called if your AJAX query was successful
              alert(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                // This callback is called if your AJAX query has failed
                alert("Error! Funcion Limite Anual");
            }
             }
        });
        }
```

Comment: What is you PHP function look like? What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: im recived  alert error
 error: function() {
                // This callback is called if your AJAX query has failed
                alert("Error! Funcion Limite Anual");
            }

Comment: Do you see anything on your console? That is usually a good place to look for what the problem is.

Comment: You don't seem to be properly ending your `data` object

Comment: Error is (UNDEFINED)

Comment: You are missing a } at the end of you data object. Besides that, it would be useful to see what the php file looks like, to see where the error may be

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

```
$(function(){


$('#help').click(function(){





    $.ajax({
        url: 'Tipos.php',
        type: 'POST', // GET or POST
         data: {"acreedor":$("#acreedor").val(),"importe2":$("#importe2").val()},
        success: function(data) { // data is the response from your php script
            // This function is called if your AJAX query was successful
          alert(data);
        },
        error: function() {
            // This callback is called if your AJAX query has failed
            alert("Error!nuevo");
        }
    });
});
```

});

Thank You